# I can not reach my BIND DNS server at home from internet

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, webserver, bind

Sorry for my weak English. First of all I am really tired of searching internet more than 10 days and no solutions at all. I really need help and i want to solve my problem and if somebody want to help, i can give my server's root access too.

Here is my story;

I have 3-4 domain names and i want to host them in my sweet home. I am working on building a CentOS 7 Linux web server and for this situation i have ordered a static IP from my ISP. I have tried lots of tuttorials and tried soo many ways to make my server reachable from internet by a domain but i could not make it. I can reach my web server from browser over my static ip, but i could not made a domain name to be forwarded :( At last i installed Plesk 12.5 on my server and it installed all necessary softwares by itself. But same thing happened and i can not reach my web server by a domain name.

My domain name is "hostcuk.com". I have registered nameservers (is1.hostcuk.com - is2.hostcuk.com) from my domain provider and forwarded them to my static IP. I have forwarded all TCP and UDP ports (from 1 - 65535) to my local IP (192.168.1.85) on my TP-Link branded modem. I have stopped my modem's firewall and also my servers firewall "firewalld". So as you can understand there is no blokage on my web server. But when i try to reach my DNS server, it returns time out error.

I really do not know what are the necessary informations should i give you in here but here are some informations. I hide my static ip with "XXX"

/etc/named.conf

```
    // $Id: named.conf,v 1.1.1.1 2001/10/15 07:44:36 kap Exp $

// -- THE FOLLOWING LINES WERE GENERATED BY PLESK. IF YOU MODIFY THEM, THEY WILL BE OVERWRITTEN WHEN THESE SETTINGS ARE MANAGED IN PLESK UI. --
options {
        allow-recursion {
                localnets;
        };
listen-on-v6 { any; };
        version "none";
        directory "/var/named/chroot/var";
        auth-nxdomain no;
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
};

key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "CeMgS23y0oWE20nyv0x40Q==";
};

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "named.root";
};

zone "0.0.127.IN-ADDR.ARPA" {
        type master;
        file "localhost.rev";
};
// -- END OF LINES GENERATED BY PLESK. --


// -- PLEASE ADD YOUR CUSTOM DIRECTIVES BELOW THIS LINE. --
// ...
// -- END OF YOUR CUSTOM DIRECTIVES. --


// -- ALL LINES BELOW WERE GENERATED BY PLESK. IF YOU MODIFY THEM, THEY WILL BE OVERWRITTEN WHEN THESE SETTINGS ARE MANAGED IN PLESK UI. --

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-transfer {
                common-allow-transfer;
        };
};
zone "deneme.com" {
        type master;
        file "deneme.com";
        allow-transfer {
                95.70.XXX.XXX;
                common-allow-transfer;
        };
};
zone "hostcuk.com" {
        type master;
        file "hostcuk.com";
        allow-transfer {
                95.70.XXX.XXX;
                common-allow-transfer;
        };
};
acl common-allow-transfer {
        none;
};
```

NS control on a VPS @ London

```
# nslookup hostcuk.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
Server:         108.61.10.10
Address:        108.61.10.10#53

** server can't find hostcuk.com: SERVFAIL
```

NS control on a VPS @ London with my static IP. 52.33.196.19 does not belong to me. I do not know what it is.

```
# nslookup @95.70.XXX.XXX hostcuk.com
Server:         hostcuk.com
Address:        52.33.196.199#53

Name:   \@95.70.XXX.XXX
Address: 54.201.82.69
```

NS control on a Windows computer that is in my LAN

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup hostcuk.com
Sunucu:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** google-public-dns-a.google.com request has timed out
```

NS control on a Windows computer that is in my LAN and DNS Server address has forwarded to my Web Server

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup hostcuk.com
Server:  hostcuk.com
Address:  192.168.1.85

Name:      hostcuk.com
Address:  95.70.212.212
```

DNS Zone file for my domain hostcuk.com

```
; *** This file is automatically generated by Plesk ***
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     is2.hostcuk.com. admin.hostcuk.com. (
                        2016091808      ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

hostcuk.com.             IN NS   is2.hostcuk.com.
hostcuk.com.             IN NS   is1.hostcuk.com.
mail.hostcuk.com.                IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
webmail.hostcuk.com.             IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
hostcuk.com.             IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
is2.hostcuk.com.                 IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
is1.hostcuk.com.                 IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
ipv4.hostcuk.com.                IN A    95.70.XXX.XXX
www.hostcuk.com.                 IN CNAME        hostcuk.com.
ftp.hostcuk.com.                 IN CNAME        hostcuk.com.
hostcuk.com.             IN MX  10 mail.hostcuk.com.
hostcuk.com.             IN TXT  "v=spf1 +a +mx -all +a:hostcuk.com"
```

Your help is really appriciated. Please ask me if you want any information that i should give.

Thank you all and waiting for your help.

Comment: "I have forwarded all TCP and UDP ports (from 1 - 65535) to my local IP"  To *which* local IP?  If you are running your webserver and DNS servers on different machines, you need to forward tcp 80 (and tcp 443) to the webserver, and udp 53 and tcp 53 to the DNS server, and not forward the remaining 131066 ports.

Comment: My local area network ip. 192.168.1.85. Webserver and DNS server is on the same server. I know i do not need to forward all ports but i want to find out if problem occurs because of any port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in to your domain registrar and change the delegation of hostcuk.com as it's currently pointed to Cloudflare. You'll want to change that to is1.hostcuk.com and is2.hostcuk.com. You'll also need to register glue records at your domain registrar, telling them the correct IP address for is1.hostcuk.com and is2.hostcuk.com.